# Providing an image or PDF file as an input to the Handwritten Math Recognition Engine

Tags: front-end, image-processing, import, pdf-format, ocr

On Windows 7 and higher *Mathematica* supports [Handwritten Math Recognition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/HandwrittenMathRecognition.html) feature (it is available under the menu **Window** — **Handwriting Input**). The interface allows to use touchscreen to draw mathematical formulas, and does a pretty good job of converting them to *Mathematica* expressions.

[image: Math Handwriting Input]

But suppose I do not want to draw a formula, but I already have an image or PDF file with a formula I want to enter (likely having much higher fidelity than my handwriting — that supposedly should make it easier to recognize correctly). Is there a user interface or API that allows to run the math recognition engine on images/PDF files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The handwriting system requires actual pen strokes to perform recognition.